# std::future<>::get empties the result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a threaded function that would return the external IP, and thought I could use it with `std::future`:

```
std::future<std::string> GetIP4;
GetIP4 = std::async([]() -> std::string
    {
        return GetWanIP();
    });
```

When later in the code I call `GetIP4.get()`, I get a `std::string`. However this empties the object, so the next time I try to call `get` from another thread it crashes.

Is this the intended behaviour of `std::future<>::get()`? Is it a scenario "I have it only once"? I didn't find anything in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get).

Comment: You are looking for `std::shared_future`

Comment: Yes, that's the designed behavior. In the page you linked to, pay extra attention to the `valid` state and how it changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From cppreference on [`std::future<T>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) :

> Any shared state is released. `valid()` is `false` after a call to this method.

And just before mentions that

> The behavior is undefined if `valid()` is `false` before the call to this function.

Since `valid()` must be `true` to call `get()` and `get()` causes `valid()` to become `false`, then it isn't possible to `get()` the same `future` result more than once.

Comment: But is this considered a shared state?

Comment: Shared state refers to state that is shared by the single producer and the single consumer of the value.